# IF function that will calculate the annual total

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can not figure this out and would greatly appreciate if someone could help me!

In cell 5, enter an IF function that will calculate the annual total. If the client has a locker (D5) is "YES" then add the cost (C5) to the locker fee B22. Otherwise the function will return the cost only. Ensure that B22 is entered as an absolute reference.

Comment: Is it a homework or assignment?  What steps did you try?

Comment: This seems to be missing a little information (besides the identity of "cell 5".  An "annual total" implies that the costs are periodic.  How many times per year is the locker fee due?  It doesn't say what cost C5 is, but is it a one-time cost or something due periodically (every time the locker fee is due?)?  Is the logic that C5 is always due but B22 is due only if D5 is "YES"?

Comment: These are the directions that my professor gave me. It is homework. It doesn't say how many times the locker fee is due. the last sentence you said is right i think. I have no fricken clue.

Comment: Terrible question.  I hope the grades are based on displaying some understanding rather than getting the right answer.  No wonder you're confused.

Answer (score 0):

The column letter appears to be left out of the "cell 5", so pick a letter.  I'll use A5 for this example.  The other defined cells are cost in C5, locker in D5, and locker fee in B22.

Since the question you were given is unclear, I would cover the bases with a couple of extra values.  Annual total implies that the costs are periodic, but no frequency is given.  So let's add a couple of placeholders just to show that you considered it.  Lets make C6 the annual frequency for "cost" and B23 the annual frequency for the locker fee.  Just stick some text in a neighboring cell to identify what these represent and make their value 1.  So the annual total will be one "cost" and one locker fee (if D5 is "YES").  That would make the formula in A5:

```
=C5*C6+IF(D5="YES",B22*B23,0)
```

Comment: @RobinPrice - That's pretty straightforward, but the key thing is that you understand how the formula works and why it gives you the answer that we're guessing is what was asked.  If you have any questions about it, post a comment on your question (which you can do with no rep, and "address" it with username as I did on this comment or nobody will be aware that the comment is there).